# Big gap on bottom of website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having this weird CSS issue that I have huge space in bottom of my webpage. I can solve it putting `height: 100%` on body, but then functions like `$(window).scroll()` function in JS don't work.

If I move my footer outside the wrapper called #sb-site, footer drops under that huge white gap.

Live Preview:
http://personaii-demo.tumblr.com/

I would be really happy if somebody could help a little!

Comment: by the way, zooming in removes this gap, it has to be a thing with height of the page

Comment: @Fanckush You might be right, but tdwells90 solution worked for now.

Comment: The problem statement is clear here, and an answer has been accepted, and CSS is on-topic.  Voting to reopen.

Comment: @LanceRoberts It lacks context. We shouldn't have to relies on the live preview. There should at least be something showing what the main elements on that page are (in particular where those wrappers are, a bit more on how the footer is implemented). This being said, it probably can be improved, and should be re-opened in this case.

Comment: @Bruno, I agree, more info should have been given in the question.

Comment: @Bruno Can I reopen it if I unaccept answer?

Comment: @AleksiTappura i just saw the answers, nice stuff! I'm discovering new things here with max height :D

Answer (score 2):

You have a min-height set of 8164px on #sb-site. I just turned it off using developer tools, it got rid of the white gap at the bottom and everything else seemed to work ok? At least for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the min height on the page.

Comment: I think you can improve your answer if you explained why removing the min-height for the page solves the problem.